# nanoHTTP with local File on android

Tags: android, file, nanohttpd

Hy,

i try to build a web server for android with local index.html but i don't get it to work.
All examples i can find gives many different errors.
I don't even find a solution to start a web server.

i try'd it with

```
public App() throws IOException {
            super(8080);
            start(NanoHTTPD.SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT, false);
            System.out.println("\nRunning! Point your browsers to http://localhost:8080/ \n");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                new App();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't start server:\n" + ioe);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
            String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
            Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
            if (parms.get("username") == null) {
                msg += "<form action='?' method='get'>\n  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" + "</form>\n";
            } else {
                msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";
            }
            return newFixedLengthResponse(msg + "</body></html>\n");
        }
```

And many more...

Could please someone post a working example for me.

thx

Comment: Are you telling that you could not find a nice example at: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this examples, but it will not work for me...

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;
import fi.iki.elonen.util.ServerRunner;

public class HelloServer extends NanoHTTPD {

  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HelloServer.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerRunner.run(HelloServer.class);
  }

  public HelloServer() {
    super(8080);
  }

  @Override
  public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    Method method = session.getMethod();
    String uri = session.getUri();
    HelloServer.LOG.info(method + " '" + uri + "' ");

    String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
    Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
    if (parms.get("username") == null) {
      msg += "<form action='?' method='get'>\n" + "  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" + "</form>\n";
    } else {
      msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";
    }

    msg += "</body></html>\n";

    return newFixedLengthResponse(msg);
  }
}
```

I've allowed internet access in Androidmanifest.xml, it compile without any errors but it wont start.